# jQuery Mobile: How to create a linked row with title and description

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

There is an example in jQuery Mobile: Up and Running which shows an interactive list containing title, description, and a link

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449331085/4dot-lists/id2712982

I can't find the code for this, and the only way I have so far been able to reproduce the same effect is to nest an `<hX>` element inside the `<a>`, which I understand is bad practice.

Can anyone suggest the correct way to achieve this? The example below works, but only by nesting the  inside the .

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>List Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head> 

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="example">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
            <h2>List Example</h2>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" >
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <h3>Title1</h3>
                    <p>Description1</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <h3>Title2</h3>
                    <p>Description2</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) (under "Text formatting & counts")

> To add text hierarchy, use headings to increase font emphasis and use
>   paragraphs to reduce emphasis.

So that seems to be the correct way to do it. That said you can nest whatever you want in the `li` and style it using `CSS'.